# Swift CORE ML recognize the object and check if it's a hand?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4, coreml, coremltools

I wanna know how to recognize if the object is a hand... If it's classification is a hand in CORE ML.
I already know how to detect the object and see all the classifications of it, but got no ideas on how to check if it's a person's hand. I also wanted to find out is it possible to detect the hand limbs - nails using CORE ML after the object is detected as a hand.

Comment: you should use turi create for object detection for hand, if hand is detected that means person has hand, or you should use CreateML for object detection

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understood it right, you don't have a model, right? 
If that's the case, you should either look for a model that can recognise a hand (I think you can find one [here](https://developer.apple.com/machine-learning/models/) or [here](https://github.com/likedan/Awesome-CoreML-Models). If that doesn't work, then you'll need to create a model. I would try to use [CreateML](https://developer.apple.com/machine-learning/create-ml/) first. You'll need labeled data (images *with* and *without* hands) for training.

As for detecting nails, fingers, etc. what you want is to check whether they are present or *where* they are? Those are two different problems (and you will need different models for each): classification or segmentation. That one would be harder to find a pretrained model I guess, so you would have to train one. Again, you could start with CreateML and if you can't get to a good model with it, maybe you could start from a model that already works for segmentation and use transfer learning training it from there with your data.